# XOR parity check with PHP

Tags: php, checksum, xor, parity

My client's PHP web application imports CSV data from a 3rd party, and I've been tasked with validating the incoming data by using a checksum to perform a parity check on each line of CSV data.  An example line from the 3rd party CSV looks like this:

```
7450122,8267632,13042013,AP130413-044024,JD012038742880009933,41
```

The last value on the line is a one-byte Hex checksum sent from the 3rd party against which I need to validate the previous characters using an XOR parity check.  The algorithm, as specified by the third party, is:

> XOR all data in the record, character by character, truncating to one byte. XORing checksum causes the sum to be zero. Do not include commas or newline characters.

I realize this is textbook CS 101 but I'm just not sure how to implement the algorithm in code, even though I do understand XOR, and what we're trying to accomplish here.  The application validating this data is written with PHP but an implementation in any similar language would be tremendously helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Basically:

```
$str = '7450......933';
$val = substr($str, 0, 1);
for($i = 2; $i < strlen($var); $i++) {
   $char = substr($str, $i, 1);
   $val ^= $char;
}
```

This will blindly do the whole string, including that checksum var. So you'll have to add some basic "is it a comma" type logic and skip over the undesirable data. It's not clear if you xor in the checksum value as well.